# Майонез на перепелином яйце. Или на перепелиных яйцах? Или из перепелиных яиц?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, падежи

Подскажите, как правильно: майонез на перепелином яйце или на перепелиных яйцах?
Какой предлог используется: **на, из, с**?

Answer (score 0):

Майонез на перепелином яйце и майонез на перепелиных яйцах - правильно. Предложный падеж говорит о составляющем продукта.
Из перепелиных яиц - Родительный падеж говорит об основе продукта.
Составляющих много и не основа имеется в виду - это Предложный падеж
Основание важно - это Родительный падеж. Например: каша на воде и каша на молоке.